# Exporting Graphs using igraph in r

Tags: python, r, igraph

I have a large igraph object that has several edge and vertex attributes that i need to write to a file and load again later (probably by a different program like python).

```
> g
IGRAPH DN-- 85000 1000000 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), numeric_var (e/n), binary_outcome1 (e/x), binary_outcome2 (e/x)
```

so what format should i use to be able to write all the edge attributes to the file format?

```
write.graph(g, file = "test1.fileextension",format = "which_format?")
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: GraphML? Make sure you are using the latest igraph version and you are only using attributes that are numeric (double), character or logical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pros & cons of the various supported formats are documented pretty well in the R `igraph` `read.igraph` help file: http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/read.graph.html. The `write.igraph` page shows support for more types of output

- `Edge List` is too simple for your needs
- `Pajek` may be too domain-specific and has some similar limitations to `GraphML`
- `Dot` might be able to do what you need (ref: http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/dotguide.pdf)
- `GraphML` wont' deal with hypergraphs, nested graphs or mixed (directed/undirected) graphs.
- `GML` says that "only node and edge attributes are used, and only if they have a simple type: integer, real or string. So if an attribute is an array or a record, then it is ignored. This is also true if only some values of the attribute are complex."
- `DL` is prbly not going to work for you.
- `NCOL` is "simply a symbolic weighted edge list" so it's prbly out, too.
- `LGL` is also prbly too simple to work.
- `DIMACS` doesn't have the extra info you need.
- `LEDA` (I believe) only supports single attributes.
- `GraphDB` also has limitations.

So, I'd give either `GraphML` and `GML` a go.

Comment: first link is broken?